# Does reference collapsing happen or not when casting

Tags: c++, casting, reference-collapsing

I am a bit confused when casting a reference to another reference. I am thinking of this in two ways and I don't know which way is correct. Here are the two ideas:

1. **When casting a reference to a reference, reference collapsing
   happens**. This means that whenever you cast a reference to another
   reference, it collapses to a reference(either LValue or RValue). For
   example, I use `static_cast` to cast a LValue reference to a RValue reference, it
   collapses down to a LValue reference due to reference collapsing
   rules.
2. **When casting a reference to a reference, reference collapsing does **not** happen and just turns the reference to the other reference**. This means that if I was to cast a reference to another reference, there is no collapsing rules and it just turns the reference to that specific reference(either LValue or RValue). For example, I was to use `static_cast` to cast a LValue reference to a RValue reference, it would become a RValue reference because it just turns the LValue reference to a RValue reference without reference collapsing.

These explanations are probably pretty hard to understand so if you have a hard time understanding them, just comment and I'll try to probably make it easier.

Here are some code snippets:

For the first one:

```
std::string func(std::string& LValue) {
    return static_cast<std::string&&>(LValue); // Does this cast it to an RValue and then reference collapsing happens causing it to become a LValue?
}


int main() {
    std::string t = "Testing";
    std::string& t1 = t;
    func(t1);
}
```

For the second one:

```
std::string func(std::string& LValue) {
    return static_cast<std::string&&>(LValue); //This casts it to a RValue. Does this turn it to a RValue and no reference collapsing happens resulting to a RValue?
}


int main() {
    std::string t = "Testing";
    std::string& t1 = t;
    func(t1);
}
```

Comment: The 2 cases look the same to me - typo ?

Comment: Also see __Reference collapsing__ here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference casts are not listed as places where reference collapsing happens.

Comment: Casts have nothing to do with reference collapsing as Richard Critten has pointed out. They apply when you are **composing types** with references such as `using T1 = int&; using T2 = T1&&;`